# what is the filter responsible for keeping the authentication object in security context in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

to my knowledge the most of the authentication filter extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and overrides `attemptAuthentication` method which is called in `dofilter` method but i do not see how the `authentication` object is placed in `securitycontext` because the `sessionstrategy` in `abstractauthenticationprocessinfilter` is  set to `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy` which does not do any thing in `onAuthentication` method so how does the security exactly work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is responsible for placing `Authentication` to the `SecurityContext`.It is done inside [successfulAuthentication()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/2b960b074b8518c81a789214e542954d82deedb8/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L316). Its javadoc also states such behaviour :

> Default behaviour for successful authentication.
>
> 1. Sets the successful Authentication object on the SecurityContextHolder
> 2. Informs the configured RememberMeServices of the successful login
> 3. Fires an InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent via the configured ApplicationEventPublisher
> 4. Delegates additional behaviour to the AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

The `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` you mentioned (which is set to `NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy` by default) is for plugging other HttpSession-related behaviour when authentication occurs such as to ensure session exists or guard against session-fixation attacks. The default behaviour (i.e. [successfulAuthentication()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/2b960b074b8518c81a789214e542954d82deedb8/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L316))  will always run no matter what strategy it is set to.